# Swap text around equal sign

Tags: vim, vi

**Is there an easy way to flip code around an equal sign in vi/vim?**

Eg:  I want to turn this:

```
value._1 = return_val.delta_clear_flags;
value._2._1 = return_val.delta_inactive_time_ts.tv_sec;
value._2._2 = return_val.delta_inactive_time_ts.tv_nsec;
value._3    = return_val.delta_inactive_distance_km;
(...)
```

into this:

```
return_val.delta_clear_flags = value._1;
return_val.delta_inactive_time_ts.tv_sec = value._2._1;
return_val.delta_inactive_time_ts.tv_nsec = value._2._2;
return_val.delta_inactive_distance_km = value._3;
(...)
```

on A LOT of lines in a file.

I know this seems a little trivial, but I've been running into lots of cases when coding where I've needed to do this in the past, and I've never had a good idea/way to do it that didn't require a lot of typing in vim, or writing a awk script.  I would think this would be possible via a one liner in vi.

Explanations of the one-liners is very welcome and will be looked upon highly when I select my accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Something like this:

```
:%s/\([^=]*\)\s\+=\s\+\([^;]*\)/\2 = \1
```

You might have to fiddle with it a bit if you have more complex code than what you have shown in the example.

EDIT: Explanation

We use the `s/`*find*`/`*replace* comand. The *find* part gets us this:

1. longest possible string consisting of anything-but-equal-signs, expressed by `[^=]*` ...
2. ... followed by one or more spaces, `\s\+` (the extra `\` in front of `+` is a vim oddity)
3. ... followed by `=` and again any number of spaces, `=\s\+`
4. ... followed by the longest possible string of non-semicolon characters, `[^;]*`

Then we throw in a couple of capturing parentheses to save the stuff we'll need to construct the replacement string, that's the `\(`*stuff*`\)` syntax

And finally, we use the captured strings in the *replace* part of the `s/`*find*`/`*replace* command: that's `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: I understand.  I meant to say that if other parts of your code are more complex, e.g. have more than a single '=' or a ';' on a line (even in a quoted expression) my solution will not work without further tweaking.

Comment: That's fine.  Usually when I have to flip stuff like that, they lines are of the format "lvalue = rvalue;" above, so your solution hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Is it a problem that this one _requires_ spaces around the equals? It won't work for "lvalue=rvalue;" I believe. depesz's solution doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Spaces are (technically) optional, but I usually write assignment statements with spaces between the lvalue,rvalue and the operator.

Answer (score 12):

For interest's sake, here's how I did it as a recorded macro:

```
qq0"+df=xA<BACKSPACE> = <ESC>"+pxi;<ESC>jq
```

Peforming that on the first line sets the "q" macro to do what's required. Then on each subsequent line you can execute the macro by typing:

```
@q
```

or, say you want to apply the macro to the next 10 lines:

```
10@q
```

I always find macros easier for a quick switch like this than figuring out the regex, because they're essentially an extension of how I would do it by hand.

**Edit**: Dan Olson points out in his comment that if you want to then apply the macro to a range of lines, for instance lines 6-100, you can enter the following. I don't know if there's a more concise syntax that doesn't require the ".*" pattern match.

```
:6,100g/.*/normal @q
```

**Explanation of the macro**

- qq

  - start recording in register q
- 0

  - go to beginning of line
- "+df=

  - delete up to the '=' and put the text into the '+' register
- x

  - delete extra space
- A

  - go to end of line and enter insert mode
- `<BACKSPACE>` = `<ESC>`

  - Delete the semicolon, insert an equals sign and a space
- "+p

  - insert the test copied earlier into register '+'
- xi;`<ESC>`

  - reinsert the trailing semicolon
- j

  - move down to the next line, ready to reapply the macro
- q

  - stop recording

Comment: I didn't know you could record macros like that in vim.

Comment: I always find that to be one of the killer vim features; before macros I would often end up in one of those repetitive loops performing the same brainless action on 20 sequential lines.

Comment: I tend to use macros like this a lot in combination with :g... for exmaple :g/something/normal @q

Comment: you can use ranges directly with the normal command ":.,+20 normal @q". I sometimes select a range of lines (shift+V) and then do a :normal <command-mode commands>

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*=\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*;\s*$/\2 = \1;/
```

should work nicely.

Comment: This works, I tried it, but I'm not sure about the \\(.\{-}\\) parts work. I know those match the code pieces on both sides of the equals sign. Can you explain how those code segments work?

Comment: ... and don't be greedy, unlike '*'

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\([^ =]*\)\s*=\s*\([^;]*\);/\2 = \1;/
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Character by character level explanations for more than 2 or 3 inches of a compressed regex would take several pages to describe to a layman.  Describing it generally considered socially unacceptable, as is unwanted medically correct psychoanalysis or calling someone fat in the grocery store.