# Swap selection around a pivot

Tags: vim

(NOT a possible duplicate of [Swap text around equal sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374105/swap-text-around-equal-sign) :)

Very often I find myself swapping things around. Which is a pain in the ass.

Let say just after I write this piece of code

```
tmp = realloc (words, sizeof (char **) * (*count + 1));
```

I notice there are just too many asterisks in a row, don't like it, and want to swap the two factors around the multiplication asterisk.

Or, I write

```
#if !defined(_CONSOLE_H_) && defined (__MINGW32__)
```

but I suddenly realize that `defined (__MINGW32__)` must come first for some reason.

I think it would be cool if I could do something like this:

(On a character `x`, `[x]` indicate cursor position. `<S>` stands for this hypothetic "swap around" command)

```
#if [!]defined(_CONSOLE_H_) && defined (__MINGW32__)
```

command: `vf&<S>$` => select from cursor to pivot (the word `&&`), and swap the selection around with the text till end of line.

Or, for the former example:

```
tmp = realloc (words, [s]izeof (char **) * (*count + 1));
```

command: `v3f*<S>f)` => select from here to third `*`, swap with text forward to `)`.

For me, it would be incredibly useful. Is there something like this out there, or I have to write my own plug-in?

Thanks!

**EDIT** -

As @ib. says in the comments to his answer, I need to be more specific as to *what* is the pivot.

The pivot could also be a character, for example here:

```
static char ** tokenize_input (char * input, PDWORD count);
```

I may want to swap the two arguments around the `","`. More precisely, the `", "`.

So maybe I'll need *two* commands:

```
<s> - char-wise - the pivot is the last character of the selection;
<S> - word-wise - the pivot is the last word of the selection.
```

Thanks!
(ps. what about the last **Word**? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work here, let me know how it does:

```
function! Swap(...) "{{{
  let start_v = col("'<")
  let end_v = col("'>")
  let mv = ''
  let isMv = 0
  while !isMv
    let char = s:GetChar()
    if char == '<Esc>'
      return ''
    endif
    let mv .= char
    let isMv = s:IsMovement(mv)
    echon mv."\r"
  endwhile
  if isMv == 2
    return ''
  endif
  exec "normal! ".end_v.'|'.mv
  let lhs = '\%'.start_v.'c\(.\{-}\S\)'
  if !a:0
    let pivot = '\(\s*\%'.(end_v).'c.\s*\)'
  else
    let pivot = '\(\s*'.a:1.'*\%'.(end_v).'c'.a:1.'\+\s*\)'
  endif
  let rhs = '\(.*\%#.\)'
  exec 's/'.lhs.pivot.rhs.'/\3\2\1/'
endfunction "Swap }}}

function! s:GetChar() "{{{
  let char = getchar()
  if type(char) == type(0) && char < 33
    return '<Esc>'
  elseif char
    let char = nr2char(char)
  endif
  return char
endfunction "GetChar }}}

function! s:IsMovement(mv) "{{{
  let ft = a:mv =~ '^\C\d*[fFtT].$'
  let ft_partial = a:mv =~ '^\C\d*\%([fFtT].\?\)\?$'
  let right = a:mv =~ '^\d*[l$|;,]\|g[m$]$'
  let right_partial = a:mv =~ '^\d*\%([l$|;,]\|g[m$]\?\)\?$'
  if !right_partial && !ft_partial
    return 2
  endif
  return ft || right
endfunction "IsMovement2Right }}}

" Use last char as pivot. e.g.: the comma in the given example.
vmap <silent> <leader>s1 :<C-U>call Swap()<CR>
" Use \S\+ (WORD) as pivot. e.g.: &&
vmap <silent> <leader>ss :<C-U>call Swap('\S')<CR>
" Use \w\+ as pivot.
vmap <silent> <leader>sw :<C-U>call Swap('\w')<CR>
```

No need to press enter to specify the movement now. The 'pivot' always includes any surrounding whitespace and it can be defined with a single character class given as argument to Swap() in the mapping.

If you want to see it highlighted, check https://gist.github.com/1921196

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't like it. It wouldn't work most of the times.

Comment: I like it!:) It would be great if I didn't have to press <CR> in the end (it feels kind of emacs-y) but I suspect it's necessary for how I described the command. However, if you find a way, let me know:) Thank you, +1 and correct!

Comment: I mean, it doesn't *have* to be like that, i.e. {selection}<S>{motion}, as I described; that's just the (rather clumsy) solution I found for the problem. Initially I thought about selecting the entire thing to swap, move the cursor on the pivot (which is not possible, it deselect part of the selection) and then <S>. So, if you find a better design, you're super welcome.

Comment: I updated the code to remove the need to press <CR>. I don't see many problems with the current approach. If you think of a simpler one or you see a problem let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose the following mapping as an implementation of the hypothetic
`<S>` command.

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader>m xm':<c-u>set opfunc=PasteAfter<cr>g@
function! PasteAfter(type)
    let [sl, sc] = getpos("'[")[1:2]
    let [cl, cc] = getpos("''")[1:2]
    let back = sl < cl || (sl == cl && sc < cc)
    undojoin | exe 'norm!' ['`]p`[', '`[P`]'][back]
endfunction
```

This implementation works not only for a character-wise selection on a single
line, but also for a line-wise and a block selections.

Comment: @Metz:  Use it the same way you describe it in your hypothetical workflow:  Select a piece of text (for example, using `v3f*`), press your leader key (which is the backslash character, by default) followed by `m`, and use a motion command (e.g. `f)`).  If it will not work, please, provide more details about your actions; I will be glad to help you make it work.

Comment: Ok it works, but it doesn't resolve the issue. It swaps things between *themselves*, not around a pivot.

Comment: @Metz:  This issue can be easily fixed as soon as you provide a strict definition of how the boundaries of the pivot segment should be determined.

Comment: You are right. In fact, I noticed the solutions from @Luc Hermitte doesn't work in the case I consider a character as the pivot (for example, if I want to swap the arguments of a function definition, the pivot would be ",", which usually is attached to the argument name before it). So, for sake of completeness, I do need two commands: <s> - the pivot is the last character of the selection, and <S> - the pivot is the last word of the selection. However, feel free to re-design the workflow of the command, my {selection}<s>{motion} is just a proposal. Thank you, +1.

Comment: @Metz, I'm not sure to understand your sentence. My solution works very well where function parameters are concerned -- `di,`+movement+`vi,g"` and the trick is done (thanks to another plugin of mine that knows what parameters are). However it has no notion of pivot.

Comment: @LucHermitte I'd prefer to stick with an homogeneous solution that can handle all cases of this swap-around-pivot problem (i.e. whatever the pivot is, a space, a character, or a word, swap these things around it), rather than install this and that plugin, one for each case. I'll consider learning vim script and give a try writing my own functions. This matter is intriguing:)

Comment: What about one or 10 lines as a pivot? The "there no such thing as a pivot" solution is the one that is truly generic and scales. :p

Answer (score 1):

I use the [following plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/vim-tip-swap-word.vim) which has been inspired by a vim tip.

First I delete (in one stroke -- `diw` also counts as one, while `xx` does not) the first part I want to swap. Then I visually select the second part. And finally I hit `g"`.

*Et voilà!* The two texts have been swapped.

Of course, It's not as simple as choosing the pivot. Which is normal, as it's not only about a pivot: we have to specify at one time or another where both texts to swap begin and end, plus the cases when the pivot is zero-length(ed?).

Comment: Thanks, I like the thing and I'll give it a try, but it doesn't answer the question. However +1

Comment: The zero-lengthed pivot case could be fired when the cursor is on a space (=the last character of the selection is a space). I edited the question specifying what is to be considered a pivot, which was somehow implicit, and @ib. reasonably pointed out the problem. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution with a somewhat different workflow.  You select the text in visual mode and then indicate the character/text you want to pivot around.  In most cases, I wanted whitespace to be taken into account, so, by default, whitespace around the pivot text is included as part of the actual pivot.  I mapped the it to sequences like \a, to pivot around a comma (with explicit mappings for ',', ';', '.', and whitespace) and \aa prompts for the pivot text, so you can use \aaand to pivot around the word "and".

Here's the vimscript:

```
vmap <silent> <leader>aa :call SwapAround()<CR>
vmap <silent> <leader>a, :call SwapAround(',')<CR>
vmap <silent> <leader>a. :call SwapAround('\.')<CR>
vmap <silent> <leader>a; :call SwapAround(';')<CR>
vmap <silent> <leader>a<Space> :call SwapAround("[ \t\n]*")<CR>

function! SwapAround(...) range
  if 1 == a:0
    let exp = a:1
  else
    call inputsave()
    let exp = input('pivot:')
    call inputrestore()
  endif
  if exp !~ '[ \t\n]' 
    let exp = '[ \t\n]*'.exp.'[ \t\n]*'
  endif
  call s:SwapAroundBase(exp, getpos("'<"), getpos("'>"))
endfunction

function! s:SwapAroundBase(sepExp, start, end) range
    let save_a = @a
    try
      let originalText = s:getText(a:start, a:end)
      let sepStart = match(originalText, a:sepExp)
      let sepEnd = matchend(originalText, a:sepExp)
      let firstOne = strpart(originalText, 0, sepStart)
      let sep = strpart(originalText, sepStart, sepEnd - sepStart)
      let secondOne = strpart(originalText, sepEnd)
      let @a = secondOne.sep.firstOne
      let posStatus = setpos(".", a:start)
      normal! v
      let posStatus = setpos(".", a:end)
      normal "ap
    finally
      let @a = save_a
    endtry
endfunction

function! s:getText(start, end)
  let lines = getline(a:start[1], a:end[1])
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: a:end[2] - 1]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][a:start[2] - 1:]
  return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction
```

This works well for single line swapping, but I think the multi-line cases need to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Select the region you want to swap. Press `<C-s>`. Let the vim do the rest. Any non-word characters would be the pivot.

```
vnoremap  <C-s> :s/\%V\(\w\+\)\(\W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1<cr>:noh<cr>
```

[image]